# Redact in mongodb seems obscure to me

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm fighting with redact right now and I'm not sure to understand it.

I just read the docs and tried to use redact on a collection grades (it comes from mongodb online training)

A document in the collection "grades" looks like this :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("50b59cd75bed76f46522c34e"),
    "student_id" : 0,
    "class_id" : 2,
    "scores" : [ 
        {
            "type" : "exam",
            "score" : 57.92947112575566
        }, 
        {
            "type" : "quiz",
            "score" : 21.24542588206755
        }, 
        {
            "type" : "homework",
            "score" : 68.19567810587429
        }, 
        {
            "type" : "homework",
            "score" : 67.95019716560351
        }, 
        {
            "type" : "homework",
            "score" : 18.81037253352722
        }
    ]
}
```

I use the following query :

```
db.grades.aggregate([
    { $match: { student_id: 0 } },
    { 
        $redact: {
            $cond: {
                if: { $eq: [ "$type" , "exam" ] },
                then: "$$PRUNE",
                else: "$$DESCEND"
            }
        }
    }
```

]
   );

With this query, each type an exam is found, this sub document should be excluded. And it works, the result is:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("50b59cd75bed76f46522c34e"),
    "student_id" : 0,
    "class_id" : 2,
    "scores" : [ 
    {
        "type" : "quiz",
        "score" : 21.24542588206755
    }, 
    {
        "type" : "homework",
        "score" : 68.19567810587429
    }, 
    {
        "type" : "homework",
        "score" : 67.95019716560351
    }, 
    {
        "type" : "homework",
        "score" : 18.81037253352722
    }
]
}
```

but if I invert the condition, I expect that only exams are kept in the result :

```
if: { $eq: [ "$type" , "exam" ] },
       then: "$$DESCEND",
       else: "$$PRUNE"
```

however the result is empty.

I don't understand why subdocument of type "exam" are not included.

Comment: Again another mongodb university homework.

Comment: @user3100115 Homework questions are not necessarily bad questions as long as they are written in a way which seeks insight and not just a finished solution which gets a good enough grade.

Comment: @Philipp However, I know from first hand experience that the students are taught each step in a rather lengthy fashion. Detailed, I might add, and the documentation isn't bad, either. From my point of view, it is the aim of each of the classes to give a student enough information so that the documentation becomes more or less a reminder. In that context, the question along with the existing query seems a bit... ...arbitrary to me.

Comment: No, it's not a university homework. I already passed the exam 2 years ago and redact wasn't there at this time. Documentation was unclear to me. I thought it was the right place to ask a question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `$redact` stage starts at the root document and its fields, and only when that document fulfills the condition to `$$DESCEND`, it examines the sub-documents included in that document. That means the first thing $redact does with your document is examine this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("50b59cd75bed76f46522c34e"),
    "student_id" : 0,
    "class_id" : 2,
    "scores" : [] // Some array. I will look at this later.
}
```

It doesn't even find a `type` field here, so `$eq: [ "$type" , "exam" ]` is false. What did you tell $redact to do when the condition is false? `else: "$$PRUNE"`, so the whole document is pruned before the sub-documents are examined.

As a workaround, test if `$type` is either `"exam"` or doesn't exist. You didn't explicitly ask for a working solution, so I will leave it as an exercise to you to figure out how to do this.

Comment: ok thanks. I wasn't looking for a solution but I was looking for an explanation and yours was great. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm trying to implement the suggested workaround but I cannot get it to work. Any example working code would be appreciated!

Comment: @papaiatis Please ask a new question with your example document and the code you have already tried.

Comment: @Philipp https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45571569/how-to-combine-redact-with-exists-in-mongodb